# UITableView going out of view

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i have a UITableView with multiple selection enabled with checkmarks. When i make selection that are all visible in the view, i don't run into any errors. However, if i scroll down further and place a selected item out of view, i get errors and even though the row stays selected, the checkmark goes away.

```
import Foundation
import Parse
import UIKit

class customerMenuVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { 

@IBOutlet weak var menuTV: UITableView!

var menuItems: [String] = ["Hello"]
var menuPrices: [Double] = [0.0]
var orderSelection: [String] = []
var priceSelection: [Double] = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

{
    return menuItems.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfColumnsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return 1;
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{
    let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "mycell")

    cell.textLabel!.text = "\(menuItems[indexPath.row])\t $\(menuPrices[indexPath.row])"

    return cell

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    //tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell!.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    orderSelection.append(cell!.textLabel!.text!)
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell!.accessoryType = .None
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    menuTV.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    let resMenu = resUser.sharedInstance
    var resName = resMenu.nameStr
    var resID = resMenu.idStr

            var menuQ = PFQuery(className: "menu")
            menuQ.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(resID){
                (menus: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil && menus != nil {
                    let items: [String] = menus?.objectForKey("menuItems") as! Array
                    let prices: [Double] = menus?.objectForKey("menuPrices") as! Array
                    self.menuItems = items
                    self.menuPrices = prices
                    self.menuTV.reloadData()
        }

    }

}

@IBAction func continueButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let selections = menuTV.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as! [NSIndexPath]
    var indexCount = selections.count
    println(indexCount)
    var x = 0
    while x < indexCount
    {
        println(x)
        let currentCell = menuTV.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selections[x]) as? UITableViewCell?;
        println(x)
        println(selections[x].row.description)
        orderSelection.append(currentCell!!.textLabel!.text!)
        println(orderSelection[x])
        x++
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how table views work.

When a cells scrolls off-screen, it gets tossed into the recycle queue and then used again to display data for a different indexPath in your data.

Any time the user makes any changes to the data for a cell you should save it to your data model (usually an array of information, or maybe an array of arrays if you're using a sectioned table view.) Then you should tell the table view to redisplay the changed cell. The cellForRowAtIndexPath method picks up the changed data and shows the changes to the cell. If the cell scrolls off-screen and then scrolls back on-screen, it gets displayed with the correct settings.

This applies to keeping track of which cells are selected as well.

Comment: right so I can save the data in an array but this brings up alot of complication when something is deselected. How exactly would i code the cellForRowAtIndexPath to keep the selected data selected even when its drawn off of the view?